# Unable to set Future Date Time in Salesforce UI or Code

Tags: apex, salesforce-classic

I work on a project which basically pulls data from NASA/ESA regarding solar eclipses happening in past and future. The issue I am facing is if I try to save the date in future like year 4017 I get an exception.

There is no code/validation rule still I am getting this error. Can someone throw some light?

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Q2800000EgUzyEAF; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Eclipse Date: invalid date: Tue Oct 31 10:29:58 GMT 4017: [Eclipse_Date__c]

PS: I tried saving from the classic UI as well, still same error.

Code to reproduce:

```
Update new Lead(id='00Q2800000EgUzy',Eclipse_Date__c=System.now().addYears(2000));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Salesforce also have a limit on a max date you entered in date-time / date field.

Maybe it's 4000 year, so you have to create text field to save the date greater than 4000 years.

From documentation: [Maximum date and year values accepted by Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240801&type=1):

> Salesforce can accept dates between Jan 1, 1700 and December 31, 4000.

Comment: Nice, good find. It is also mentioned in help article: [Maximum date and year values accepted by Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240801&type=1)

Comment: I think so. The only issue is then I won't be able to group by in reports etc. As text filed basically defeats purpose of having date field

Comment: @Pranay, this is a Salesforce limit and I don't think you can do anything about it.

Comment: I agree. Let's see what other solution people can come up with , or we can change that limit calling salesforce support.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - group by? there is no group by for centuries so it is not clear how useful group by is for date that span that great a range

Comment: @cropredy Make sense.